# Change the application's size when open app from protocol, outside of constructor

Tags: c#, uwp

I have problem related to open application from uri protocol, after click I want my application size start with specific size. I do some search and found this [forum conversation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2c4cc214-96cf-4e0f-aeaa-c77c23ae1984/uwphow-to-change-the-default-window-size-of-an-uwp-launched-from-launcherlaunchuriasync-or-its?forum=wpdevelop) which said that kind of thing is impossible.

I want to change application size not in the constructor, but in the function `OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)`.

Comment: Are you the developer of the other app? ie do you have any control over this

Comment: I can control my app, I want to open my app from the website via uri using protocol activation

Answer (score 0):

Resizing the Application view is possible within the `OnActivated` handler. When the `Window` is activated, you can use the `ApplicationView.TryResizeView` method to change the size of your app view.

```
public bool TryResizeView(Size value)
```

This call tries to resize your app view and returns a boolean of whether the operation was successful. For example you can do the following:

```
var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
if (view.TryResizeView(new Size { Width = 600, Height = 500 }))
{
    //window was resized
} 
else
{
    //unable to resize
}
```

Comment: thanks Martin, in case my app is already opened, I click uri to open my app, do you have any suggestion to change the current opened app size?

Comment: This approach should be able to realize the already open application view as well, isn't it?